# How to plot various address on Google Maps using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, google-maps

I'm creating a Dashboard on Excel 2010 to show all the sales on a map. I would like to add browser window inside Excell showing the map and all the address.

The list of addresses are in a MS Sql database and I will bring then based on the user´s filters on a form.

If possible, I would like to display extra info on the Map when users click on the map (like client name, date of sale...)

Does anyone have a file with this solution already implemented ?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code repository. Doubtless what you want can be done. Google Maps has an API which can be used and browser controls can be embedded in Excel. Once you decide on what you want to do and are at the point of writing actual code, you can ask questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Please take 20 seconds to take the [tour], and then five more minutes to read the [help/on-topic].

Comment: FYI - Excel 2016 has a really neat [Maps function](https://www.journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2017/mar/excel-2016-mapping-tools.html). I know you have 2010, but if it's that important, perhaps upgrading would be worth it.

Comment: @BruceWayne Cool. I've been using Excel 2010 for years but the school I work at is in the process of upgrading this semester. Things to look forward to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. The Q&A format of Stack Overflow does not lend itself this sort of question. Questions such as this don't really work with objective answers. If you are looking for tutorials on how to do something such as this best bet is to do a Google search, and if you have a specific question such as you have tried something and it isn't working then that would be a more appropriate question for this sort of format.

Comment: Oh also, search for exporting Excel data to Google Earth. I've done it in the past and you can load the KML into Earth and it'll show the location, and any additional info you want when you click the pin.

Answer (score 1):

Geocoding is the process of converting addresses to the x and y coordinate or longitude and latitude. There are various option available in the market to perform geocoding, some are paid and some are free. You can use [The Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to retrieve the longitude and latitude for free.

For further information see: [Geocoding using Microsoft Excel 2013 and Google Maps API](http://grindgis.com/software/microsoft-excel/geocoding-excel-and-google).

So, you can use Excel add-ins to add on to Excel's out-of-the-box functionality. 
See [Excel Google Maps Add-In](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1036941/Excel-Google-Maps-Add-In) and give it a try for your needs.